# unable to wake up windows 8.1 pro from sleep, it shows only black screen

Tags: windows-8, wake-up

I m unable to wake up my windows 8.1 pc from sleep mode on scheduled time, it always shows black screen on waking and hangs on it,no mouse or keyboard keys works, I have to only restart.
please help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is a desktop Windows 8.1, have you tried removing the mains power, pressing the power on/off button and then reconnecting the mains power? Hopefully it will then reboot.